# What does 'a "guy" guy' mean?

Tags: meaning

Manager saw Linda's son Frank roaming with Karl:

> Manager: What about me?
>
> Linda: He doesn't see you as a **"guy" guy**.
>
> Manager: Karl's a **"guy" guy**?

What does 'a "guy" guy' mean?

Comment: What is the source of this dialogue?

Comment: I suspect the text is more like "Karl's a guy's guy" meaning Karl is a guy who respected or admired by other guys. A similer phrase would be "Karl's a man's man". See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184864/a-mans-man-and-a-ladies-man

Comment: @KateBunting Sling Blade movie

Comment: This is not necessarily a guy's guy at all. In English we repeat words for emphasis: A guy guy as opposed to a girly guy. So for me, it means a real guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is possibly more than one way this could be understood, depending on context. In the context you give it seems pretty clear it means a man (guy) that fits the other man's definition of what a man is, or should be. It could be because he does not conform to a particular masculine stereotype.

This isn't particularly an idiomatic expression, but the grammar and punctuation make it pretty clear to an English speaker. The use of quotation marks around the first instance of 'guy' frame that as the person's definition of what a 'real' man is.

There is a similar expression, "a man's man", which is defined as being a man that has traditionally masculine interests and activities. This normally has the inference that their interests make them good company for other men.

Comment: I think you got a little lost in the chain of who's talking about whom. I haven't seen the movie and have no idea of the character dynamics, but it appears that Linda is telling "Manager" what her son Frank thanks of "Manager" (and, the manager implies, of Karl).

Comment: @AndyBonner you're right, I don't think it changes my definition, I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

[Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Guy%20Guy) has a good definition for this "guy" guy, but first I'd like to state that it is not grammatically correct, nor is the phrase in any real dictionaries anywhere. Urban dictionary is a so-called **slang**-dictionary.

> A Guy Guy is usually an immature male who is obsessed with the college life. They do not live near beach towns, but during the summer that's where they can be found. They can be seen usually on 32nd street in Longport NJ in their Old Navy flowered board shorts, a white wife beater tank top, addidas flip flops(sometimes with socks), a puka shell necklass tight around their neck, usually sporting an upside down visor and spiked or gelled and high lighted hair. They can be heard talking to their Guy Guy friends about frats, college parties and girls. They usually spend their time tossing a foot ball around between themselves or strollng the shore line looking for women. They are insecure and gay and are having a hard time hiding it.

Comment: What's wrong with the grammar?

Comment: @Lambie There's nothing wrong with the grammar, really, but "guy" guy is not correct to use. It is more of a *slangy* way to talk.

Comment: Well, I would not use the term incorrect grammar then. It's more like colloquial speech.

Comment: Thanks! It's not uncalled-for to note that it's colloquial usage, but do note that the OP didn't ask whether it was proper, just what it means.